# Is this $f_B = \inf_\limits{b \in B}|x -b|$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with $A$ compact. Show that there exists a point $a \in A$ such that: for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $|a - b| \le |x - y|$.

I am trying to use this function $f_B = \inf_{b \in B}|x -b|$ to get started on this proof. In order to proceed, I believe I have to show this is continuous, but I'm stumped at the moment. Any hints please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, $|f_B(x)-f_B(y)| \leq |x-y|$. To see that note that if $b \in B$ then $|x-b| \leq |y-b|+|x-y|$. Hence $f_B(x) \leq |y-b|+|x-y|$. Taking infimum over $b \in B$ we get $f_B(x) \leq f_B(y)+|x-y|$. Hence $f_B(x) - f_B(y)\leq |x-y|$. Interchanging $x$ and $y$ we get $f_B(y) - f_B(x)\leq |x-y|$. Together these inequalities give $|f_B(x)-f_B(y)| \leq |x-y|$. and hence $f_B$ is continuous.